# Why in my triple venn diagram, the circles with no overlap, isolated from other circles in R?

Tags: r, overlap, venn-diagram

Why my circles with no overlap isolated from others?
I want to show there is no overlap between them, but the triple shape of venn diagram completely have changed with mix of two circles and one.
I need mixed circles together.

```
a1<-c("a","b")
a2<- c("a","b","c")
a3<- c("x","y")
x<-list(a1,a2,a3)
venn.diagram(x, "test.tiff",category.names=c("a1","a2","a3"))
```

This is my venn diagram chart:
[image]

Comment: Please post the code, that sets up your problem and a solution attempt.

Comment: @AlexNe Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: No. But thats necessary for anyone to fix it.

Comment: @vqf Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `VennDiagram` package, you can get the desired result with `gplots`. You just need to name the list.

```
library(gplots)

a1<-c("a","b")
a2<- c("a","b","c")
a3<- c("x","y")
x<-list(a1,a2,a3)

# New lines
names(x) = c("a1","a2","a3")
venn(x)
```

This will give you the following plot:

[image: venn diagram]